# macOS Catalina Beta 10.15 - Relocated Items after Update

Tags: macos, updates, macos-catalina

I just updated my MacBook Pro with the new macOS Catalina Beta 10.15. Everything works fine but now I have a 'Relocated Items' dir on my Desktop.

I run a tree command and this is the content of the dir:

https://pastebin.com/APa9acV8

Can somebody tell me what to do with these?

Answer (score 0):

The first one's a (localized/multilingual) PDF, the second may be a copy of your user accounts database. The last one is a virtual memory swapfile you can just throw away.

You can probably view the PDF to see if it's something you want to file away properly (according to your own preferences for organizing your files)  or just delete.

As for the accounts database, if you can successfully log into all the macOS user accounts you care about, then you probably don't need this copy. Just throw it away. Back it up first if you're worried.

Comment: Thx, I made a backup and deleted the whole dir.